# How to change all types from interface to string?

Tags: typescript

I receive a form on a server. The form can only contain keys from `User` interface. But since it is encoded, all its values will be strings. I can parse them before inserting them in my database, but I need to inform typescript that all the data received have `User` keys with string type.

Basically, how to make this:

```js
// base
interface User {
name: string;
hobbies: string[];
age: number;
}

// desired output
interface User {
name: string;
hobbies: string;
age: string;
}
```

Obviously, the model is quite long so it's not an option to copy/paste it and replace all its type with a string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
type NewUser = {
  [P in keyof User]: string;
};
```